# Which is more efficient for performing simple actions, Python, or Logic bricks?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

Basically, I am trying to find the most efficient way to do simple actions, such as moving objects. I started thinking, what is the game engine actually doing with the logic bricks? is it handling them any different then it would handle a python script to do the same thing? And, if it is handling them any differently, which is faster and more efficient for the game engine to compute?

[image: Logic for moving cube]

Comment: Great question. I wish I could have up voted it twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since BGE is written in C in the blender sources it will most likely be a few micro seconds faster than scripting in python that needs to be parsed.

You can test your timings with the "timeit" python module.

in the python console just type:

```
import timeit
help("timeit")
```

for the pydoc in blender.