# Blender Game without python?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

Is python necessary for creating any game in blender, or can I create a game in blender ONLY with Logic bricks (Sensors, Controllers & Actuators) and no python scripts?

Comment: Related: [BGE: Can Python do more than the Logic Bricks?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/62449/2217)

Comment: As always, "it depend". You can create simple games with no coding, but for more complex one you will need to write some scripts. For developers is impossible create logic bricks for everything what users can devise. Anyway, scripting is something like custom logic brick only expressed by text. Or opposite: logic bricks are scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can describe the game's behavior with logic bricks only.

Be aware some behavior is not possible to be described with pre-defined logic bricks. The custom Python controller allows you to deal with that.